# Connection Failed MongoDB ODBC Data Source Configuration

Tags: mongodb, odbc

I have downloaded and installed all relevant drivers, when I attempt to connect from windows 10 ODBC to my mongodb database (Ubuntu 18.04) I receive the error "Connection Failed [MongoDB][ODBC 1.3(w) Driver] Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading final connect information', system error: 2"

My mongosqld instance sees the connection, and appears to accept it, but then there is an automatic disconnect.